# How can I use a separate email for job inquiries?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, email, stack-overflow-jobs

Due to excessive spamming from indiscriminate, spammy recruiters, I have a separate email alias for job inquiries.  I'd like to use it for the job search-related areas of Stack Overflow but still use my regular email address for everything else.

How can I do that?

Comment: Currently not possible - should be possible.  Addition of a seperate email field that defaults to your SO related email and editable.

Answer (score 6):

You can't and it's *very* unlikely that we'll allow this.

Historically we've had a bit of a mess of email addresses that we're finally getting on top of. We had community emails which were often not correctly verified, emails associated with login credentials that are *sometimes* verified (because they come from trusted providers like Google) and also the email address associated with legacy careers.stackoverflow.com accounts before we moved everything to /jobs.

We're moving to a single verified address for all Stack Exchange emails which you have full control over using the [email settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) views in your profile.

For /jobs emails; you'll only ever receive email from recruiters if your Developer Story is configured to be visible to employers - it must be complete enough and your status must be 'Actively looking' or 'Open, not actively looking'. Our house rules are pretty strict with employers about spam so you should never receive an email that is spammy but in the event you do there are reporting mechanisms in place and we act upon these to stamp out bad behaviour.

I'm marking this [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) because we have no plans to move to a multiple email address model.

Answer (score -13):

Probably you need to create two separate accounts with your email addresses and use them as accordingly. By this way you can use your alias email for job enquiries.

Comment: It appears you've ignored my original request.  I don't want two accounts, I want one with two emails.